# How does $\frac{k^2(k+1)^2}{4} + (k+1)^3$ become $\frac{(k+1)^2(k+2)^2}{4}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing, factoring, fractions

As part of an induction proof, the authors of a beginner combinatorics text reduce/factor a polynomial as follows, but do not show the minutiae of their algebraic steps:

$$\frac{k^2(k+1)^2}{4} + (k+1)^3 \tag1$$

manipulated to:

$$(k+1)^2\left(\frac{k^2}{4} + k + 1\right) \tag2$$

manipulated to:

$$\frac{(k+1)^2}{4}(k^2 + 4k + 4) \tag3$$

manipulated to:

$$\frac{(k+1)^2(k+2)^2}{4} \tag4$$

...which was the desired result.

I fear I'm missing some sort of basic algebra required to understand what factoring and reduction steps the authors took to produce the results above. Would anyone be kind enough to explain what algebraic rules/properties/factorization allowed the authors to produce the results as shown? I've been struggling to work it out on my own.

Comment: Don't worry if you can't go from one expression to the next in one step, it may take a couple. Do you know what happened from the first expression to the second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (1), we can separate the $\frac{k^2}{4}$ from $(k+1)^2$ and move out a factor of $k+1$ from $(k+1)^3$, giving us

$$\frac{k^2}{4}(k+1)^2+(k+1)(k+1)^2$$

We can then collect like terms (specifically, the $(k+1)^2$ terms), giving us

$$(k+1)^2\left(\frac{k^2}{4}+k+1\right)$$

Which is (2).

From there, we can divide and multiply by $4$, giving us

$$(k+1)^2\cdot\frac{4}{4}\left(\frac{k^2}{4}+k+1\right)$$

Rearranging slightly gives

$$\frac{(k+1)^2}{4}\cdot4\left(\frac{k^2}{4}+k+1\right)$$

Applying the distributive law gives

$$\frac{(k+1)^2}{4}\left(k^2+4k+4\right)$$

Now we note that $k^2+4k+4=(k+2)^2$ (you can verify this yourself by expanding the RHS), thus we have the end result

$$\frac{k^2(k+1)^2}{4}+(k+1)^3=\frac{(k+1)^2(k+2)^2}{4}$$

Comment: This is a really good answer, I thank you. It appears the two most key things I didn't understand were: not spotting the ability to pull a common factor from expression (1), and not realizing I could apply division and multiplication in the manner shown to get from (2) to (3). I feel dumb but have learned a lot.

Comment: Hi, I'm glad my post was able to help you. After you ask a question here, if you get a good answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some comments:

- from line (1) to (2), he just factored the common expression $(k + 1)^{2}$ out.
- from line (2) to (3), he multiplied and divided $k + 1$ by $4$.
- from line (3) to (4), he completed the square.

If you still need any further explication, let me know.